# Not able to send movies to my phone

Tags: nokia-lumia-535

I am using Lumia 535. Whenever I try to copy any movie file from my computer to the phone, the copying gets hanged. Then, if I check my phone, it says Low Storage, besides having loads of memory. Yesterday, I tried again after updating, copying got completed, but after that when I tried deleting my cache memory using the app, the same problem occurred again. It always needs restart and then scanning of SD card. Please suggest something.

Comment: Can you include a screen shot from Storage Sense to show how much space there is, and also where new videos are stored to.

Comment: Videos are being copied to the videos folder in sd card. Storage sense shows 99% full space. Cache of about 3.5 GB is cleared afterwards.

Comment: Are you saying that it shows 99% full *before* you copy the file? If so, you definitely need to free up space before you'll be able to copy stuff to it.

Answer (score 1):

If it's showing 99% full, then delete some stuff to free some space up; you can tap on the space used bar to show a break down of where the space is being used, most options then have another level that you can drill into to manage apps/files as required.

Comment: But sir, the memory is not actually 99%. When I transfer a movie into sd card, the cache of about 3.5 GB fills the card automatically.

Comment: If Storage Sense says it is 99% in use, then it is 99% in use - you can use this same app to find out *what* is using the space, and clear some space.

Comment: Ok. Thnx for the suggestion.